# Inserting large text data into postgres with python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to do a bulk insert of long xml strings as text into a postgresql 9.1 database. I am using Python 3.2 and pyscopg2. I am enclosing the xml string in $$ and using a named variable in the query string. For example:

```
query = "insert into cms_object_metadata (cms_object_id, cms_object_metadata_data, cms_object_metadata_type_id, \
         cms_object_metadata_status_id) values ((select id from cms_objects where cms_object_ident = %(objIdent)s), \
         $$%(objMetaString)s$$, (select id from cms_object_metadata_types where cms_object_metadata_type_name = 'PDAT'), \
         (select id from cms_object_metadata_status where cms_object_metadata_status_name = 'active'))"
```

I then construct a dictionary object as follows:

```
dataDict = {'objIdent':objIdent, 'objMetaString':objMetaString}
```

passing in the objIdent and objMetaString values. I do the insert with the following code:

```
dbCursor.execute(query, dataDict)
```

When it inserts the objMetaString value into the database it contains single quotes around the string. If I append the values into the query string and execute the insert without the named variable it does not. For example:

```
query = "insert into cms_object_metadata (cms_object_id, cms_object_metadata_data, cms_object_metadata_type_id, \
         cms_object_metadata_status_id) values ((select id from cms_objects where cms_object_ident = %s), \
         $$%s$$, (select id from cms_object_metadata_types where cms_object_metadata_type_name = 'PDAT'), \
         (select id from cms_object_metadata_status where cms_object_metadata_status_name = 'active'))" % (objIdent, objMetaString)
```

and the insert:

```
dbCursor.execute(query)
```

My question is how to do a bulk insert of large text data using named variables and $$. I don't really want to have to either pre or post process this string if possible since they may be large and contain an unknown number of either single quotes, or other symbols that will need to be delimited.
I have read the following documentation and searched on stackoverflow for the answer, but have not found the solution:

- [Pyscopg2 docs](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)
- [Postgresql docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html)

Comment: What makes you so sure that your large text data doesn't contain `$$` so that you don't have to escape that as well?

Comment: If my understanding from reading this is correct then you shouldn't have to worry about any $'s in the string. Quote from Postgresql docs: 4.1.2.4. Dollar-Quoted String Constants - Notice that inside the dollar-quoted string, single quotes can be used without needing to be escaped. Indeed, no characters inside a dollar-quoted string are ever escaped: the string content is always written literally. Backslashes are not special, and neither are dollar signs, unless they are part of a sequence matching the opening tag.

Comment: You should have to worry.  See last sentence of what you quoted.

Comment: You're right, but I'm still wondering the best way to handle this, do I need to parse the full string and escape where necessary and not use the $$ syntax. I don't mind checking the opening tag for them, but was hoping to avoid parsing all the text in each string. In our particular case we are creating the xml and inserting the values, so I have some control over the xml but not the values. There must be a standard way of doing this???

Comment: The standard way of doing this is to let the driver handle it, like in your first code example.

Comment: Thanks for the help Peter, that's what I've ended up doing, but then I have to strip the single quotes off the xml strings when I pull them out of the db and use them. It's not a terrible solution but I had hoped there was a way to do this without that extra step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarizing the comment thread.  Do this:

```
query = "insert into cms_object_metadata (cms_object_id, cms_object_metadata_data, cms_object_metadata_type_id, \
         cms_object_metadata_status_id) values ((select id from cms_objects where cms_object_ident = %(objIdent)s), \
         %(objMetaString)s, (select id from cms_object_metadata_types where cms_object_metadata_type_name = 'PDAT'), \
         (select id from cms_object_metadata_status where cms_object_metadata_status_name = 'active'))"

dataDict = {'objIdent':objIdent, 'objMetaString':objMetaString}

dbCursor.execute(query, dataDict)
```

*Don't* put quotes around the `%(objMetaString)s` placeholder in your query.  It's the driver's job to quote the value if necessary.